# does push_back() "new" an object before to add to the std::list in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stl

I am new to c++ standard library. I want use std::list. I know if I create a list by myself instead of using stl, I should allocate memory to a new object, and then add it to the list.

*a c-style list of class A:*

```
A *ptrA = new A();     
ptrA->setElement(value);
ptrA->next = null;
currentPositionMyCstyleList->next = ptrA;
ptrA->prev = currentPositionMyCstyleList;
```

If I using stl, is it necessity to "new" an object? Does push_back() "new" an object before to add to the std::list in c++?

*Does Code below correct?*

```
A aObj(value);     
listA.push_back(aObj); // Will push_back() "new" an object and copy the value of aObject to the object before add it to list
```

*Will the value of aObj be released in code below:*

```
funcAddToList() {
    A aObj(value);     
    listA.push_back(aObj);
}
funcDispList() {
    // display listA  // Does the value of aObj still in list?
}
```

What does push_back() actually do?

I still confuse after reading [stl_list.h_push_back()](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_list.h#L1097)  , [_M_insert](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_list.h#L1768), [_M_create_node](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_list.h#L566)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's not a good way of implementing a C-style list of `A`. The list implementation should not be intermingled with `A` (except in rare performance-sensitive circumstances). You don't need `new` to create objects like you do in Java.

Comment: Since you are new to C++, it is worth noting that `std::vector` is usually the default container to use. `std::list` is a better choice when you have larger collection s and insert/remove elements at random positions frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the container's template argument is of a POD type, then `push_back` allocates a new memory block for it an initializes with the passed value. If the template argument is an object of a complex data type a-ka class, then it also gets allocated, and then instantiated with the copying constructor call (the parameter to the copying constructor will be the passed argument to the `push_back`).

Comment: What if class A do not have a copying constructor.

Comment: Case 1) It is private -> compilation error; Case 2) It is not declared -> The default copying constructor will be used (not a good idea actually).

Comment: So, it will be moved, if there is no copying constructor for class A.

Answer (score 2):

The `push_back` method from `std::list` will copy or move your argument.

Internally, it is up to the implementation to deal how it wants to manage the object.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::list` can contain objects or pointer to objects.

```
std::list<MyObj> list1;
list.push_back(MyObj()); // push an anonymous object (rvalue)
MyObj a;
list.push_back(a); // push (copy) a

std::list<MyObj*> list2;
list2.push_back(new MyObj());
MyObj* b = new MyObj();
list2.push_back(b);
```

`list1` is a list of MyObj, when you clear the list, instances of MyObj inside the list are destroyed and the memory is freed.
`list2` is a list of pointers, when you clear the list, instances are not destroyed.

`push_back` creates a copy of the argument on the heap. But `list2` is a list of pointers, so only the pointer is copied, not the object itself.

An anonymous object (called rvalue), due to its temporary behavior, may be "moved" inside the list: memory isn't allocated, but the pointer inside the list will point to the already allocated memory. This behavior depends on the type and on the implementation of push_back.

Comment: `step 1:  allocate memory using size of MyObj()`  `step 2: copy MyObj() to the new memory area`  `step 3: pointer in list point to the new memory area` Does push_back() do these steps to anonymous object and a named object?

Comment: An anonymous object (called **rvalue**), due to its temporary behavior, may be "moved" inside the list: memory isn't allocated, but the pointer inside the list will point to the already allocated memory. This behavior depends on the type and on the implementation of push_back.

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood...

The list has an allocator. The default allocator simply calls through to `new` (as you'd expect).
You can provide an alternate allocator if that suits.

Since you're using C++11 you might benefit from `emplace_back` which should avoid any construct/move/release overheads you're incurring.

`emplace_back` will still call the allocator though...

Alternatively it might help if you 'move' the value in:

```
list.push_back(std::move(v));
```

That's assuming you've defined useful move semantics on your element type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `push_back` from `std::list` creates a new object on heap using `new` (or `malloc()`). It creates a copy of the argument.

---

Your second snippet is correct. `aObj` is copied.

In the third snippet copy of `aObj` will remain in the list, while `aObj` itself will be deleted.